# Assigning a command output to a shell script variable

Tags: shell, unix

How do I assign a command output to a shell script variable.

```
echo ${b%?} | rev | cut -d'/' -f 1 | rev
```

`${b%?}` gives me a path..for example: `/home/home1`

The above command gives me home1 as the output. I need to assign this output to a shell script variable.

I tried the below code

```
c=${b%?} |rev | cut -d '/' -f 1 | rev

echo $c
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To assign output of some command to a variable you need to use command substitution :

`variable=$(command)`

For your case:

```
c=$(echo {b%?} |rev | cut -d '/' -f 1 | rev)
```

Just wondering why dont you try

```
basename ${b}
```

Or just

```
echo ${b##*/}
home1
```

If you want to trim last number from your path than:

```
b="/home/home1"
echo $b
/home/home1
b=${b//[[:digit:]]/}
c=$(echo ${b##*/})
echo ${c}
home
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like this:

```
variable=`command`
```

Comment: Nesting is difficult by using `backticks`

Comment: Should have no problem with c=\`${b%?} |rev | cut -d '/' -f 1 | rev\`

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.  In particular, it's probably worth mentioning why `$(...)` is superior to `\`...\``.